# Prevent my own site from setting (3rd party) cookies

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

Is there a way to make my own site (e.g. by header or js) prevent third party cookies (in my specific case one set by HTTP header of a banner embedded and one set by my twitter widget's javascript) from being set?

This should not affect the user's session (set by HTTP header as expires on session end).

The obvious alternative would be getting rid of those 3rd party includes by letting my server cache the banner and implementing the twitter feed myself using the api, but especially the latter case would mean much more work.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you are referencing content from other sites within your HTML/CSS/JavaScript you can't place any further constraints on what those sites do unless you explicitly block all the content from the remote site by your content security policy (which rather defeats the reason for incorporating the content in the first place).

Comment: so fetching&caching the image on the server side and implementing my own twitter feed are the only way to get my users rid of those trackers? guess i'll have to do that then. don't like 3rd party trackers on my page, I don't even use GA but instead parse my server logs if interested in any usage stats